# neo4j match statement slow performance

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying neo4j with 20 million nodes. When I call a simple match statement like "MATCH (n:MYLABEL {Id:5}) RETURN n", it takes about 2 minutes from the web interface and also from the console. Is there something wrong about taking that much time?

Comment: it could depend on how your graph is organized (not only size) could you add some details on how your nodes are connected?

Comment: There is no connection between nodes yet. There are 4 properties on each node with integer values and I tried to test how fast it retrieves a node from db.

Comment: I'm not sure on how Neo4j works but graph traversal algorytms usually go trough nodes links. not having links in a so big database could be the problem.

Comment: This might be the reason of slow performance, I'll try with connections thank you for your advice

Comment: If you have an index and haven't misspelt anything (case sensitive) then it should return in a few milliseconds! `create index on :MYLABEL(Id);` Please share your visual query profile. `PROFILE MATCH ... `

Comment: When I use the node id by running the query 'MATCH (n:MYLABEL) Where ID(n)=300001 return n', it returns in milliseconds; however, matching through an attribute takes much more time even with index.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to create an index on this label and property?

Comment: Yes, the statement run on the indexed property. Without index it takes about 10-12 mins. Is it normal for such a database with millions of nodes or there is something wrong in the configuration?

Comment: Something is wrong either with your computer, config, disk.

Comment: Thank you for comments, I'll try it on a different machine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the configuration of my windows machine. I tried it with a mac and the performance becomes very good. I can match an indexed attribute within 0.1 second in a database of 10 millions nodes. Thank you all for suggestions.